# Mongod: /data/db not found., terminating

Tags: mongodb

I have a strange issue:

when I type in my shell: `$ mongod`
I get this error:

```
NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
```

Well in mongod.conf file I defined my **dbPath** to be:

```
/var/lib/mongodb
```

so I am not sure why it choose to look at a different place?

When I run: `$ mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf` 
I get this error:
`F CONTROL  [main] Failed global initialization: FileNotOpen: Failed to open "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"`

However running mongo works and I have access to my databases, but I am afraid I might run into problems later. So any clue how to fix everything?

mongod.conf:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Comment: Can you post full text of mongod.conf?

Comment: You will find it now in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Any change in defaults set in the conf file would warrant a service restart. You will have to run `sudo service mongod restart`.

There's an exist8ing thread on this topic - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205412/mongodb-failed-global-initialization-failed-to-open-var-log-mongodb-mongo

Comment: I did run `sudo service mongod restart.` otherwise, I could not run mongo in my case. But still, mongod outputs this error.